# Arithmetic syntax error only on alpine linux

Tags: linux, bash, alpine-linux

I'm really new to bash and just started today to scripting a little scheduler. After testing it on mac and ubuntu everything worked fine. But when I wanted to execute it within an alpine linux an error is thrown: arithmetic syntax error. I can't understand why this is the case and couldn't find a solution on uncle google. I hope someone could help me.

This is the expression:

```
[ $((10#$(date +"%H%M") != 10#$START_TIME)) = 1 ]
```

In context showing how this is run:

```
#!/bin/bash

START_TIME=2100
END_TIME=2200

#  arithmetic syntax error
while [ $((10#$(date +"%H%M") != 10#$START_TIME)) = 1 ]; do 
    sleep 10;
done
```

Comment: You can reproduce that outside Alpine -- just need to test anywhere `sh` is implemented by `ash` or `dash`.

Comment: BTW, I'm assuming you run `sh scriptname`? Since it has a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, that indicates that it was written to run only on systems with `bash` installed, and to use `bash` as its interpreter. Alpine doesn't ship bash -- it has smaller, faster-to-start shells such as `dash`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy .. Huh? Noted your comment `The # isn't treated as a comment when it's in the middle of a word` for my now deleted answer.. Oh my, Oh my. Thank you for that insight. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is relying on syntax that isn't POSIX-specified to ensure that values are parsed as decimal numbers even if they start with leading 0s.

The easy answer is "don't do that" -- which is to say, either use string comparisons rather than numeric ones, or trim your leading 0s a different way if you need to run with baseline-POSIX interpreters.

Sticking with the numeric route: It's inefficient to use `sed` for the job, for example, but it works:

```
START_TIME=2100 # this already doesn't start with a 0
while [ $(( $(date +"%H%M" | sed -e 's/^0+//') != START_TIME )) = 1 ]; do
  sleep 10
done
```

Or, using a string comparison directly:

```
START_TIME=2100 # exactly four digits
while [ "$(date +"%H%M")" != "$START_TIME" ]; do
  sleep 10
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, what would you prefer how the script should look like for the most efficient way?

Comment: If you want to optimize for runtime efficiency *after* startup, I'd install bash instead of using `/bin/sh` -- that way you could replace `date` with `printf '%(%H%M)T'` and not have any subshells invoking external processes at all.

Comment: (mind you, doing that with no subshells would mean a separate assignment; ie. `while printf -v current_time '%(%H%M)T' && [[ $current_time != $START_TIME ]]; do` -- note that I'm switching from numeric to string comparisons there; no reason for a numeric comparison for an exact equality check).

Comment: maybe you can help me one last time:
`while printf -v current_day '%(%A)T' && [[ ${DAYS,,} != *"${current_day,,}"* ]] || printf -v current_time '%(%H%M)T' && [[ $current_time != $STOP_TIME ]]; do`
-> error it tells me:  printf: command not found, I'm sure i've made a mistake in the condition :/

Just tried to connect those conditions together but i can't figure it out how it should be correctly that it works :S I want to achieve that the script is also able to run only within certain weekdays at specific hours.

Comment: If I correctly gather that you want to group each `printf` with the test that follows, that might look something like: `while { printf -v current_day '%(%A)T' -1 && [[ ${DAYS,,} != *"${current_day,,}"* ]]; } || { printf -v current_time '%(%H%M)T' -1 && [[ $current_time != $STOP_TIME ]]; }; do`. BTW, it's arguably bad form for `DAYS`, `CURRENT_TIME` and `STOP_TIME` to be all-caps; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, fourth paragraph: All-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the OS or shell; other names are reserved for application use.

Comment: (The `-1`s mean "current time"; http://shellcheck.net/ throws warnings without them, even though `printf` does the right thing either way).

Comment: ...anyhow, if you have further issues following that approach, I'd suggest a new question.

Comment: Why not just use string comparison here: `[ "$(date +%H%M)" != $START_TIME ]`? At worst, this requires `START_TIME` to be a 4-digit time with leading zeros, but that seems like a reasonable requirement.

Comment: @chepner, yes, I arrived there myself earlier (though never incorporated that into the answer) -- read the comment history. It's worth incorporating, though; doing that now.